# Shopware 6 | Password reset do not work get validation error

Tags: symfony, shopware

When a customer tries to reset his password, the user get an error message. I enabled the dev mode to see a better error message and getting this issue.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked at the [Shopware Slack channel](https://slack.shopware.com/) and someone gets the same issue.
He debugged it and could found out, that the storefront URL is not valid.
The URL in the backend was created with a slash at the end. My URL looked like `https://www.shopware.com/` this creates an issue because the URL is "not valid" and should not have a slash at the end.

A work a round is to remove the slash at the end in your storefront URL settings. You need to change from `https://www.shopware.com/` ⇾ `https://www.shopware.com`

Comment: It is a showare bug and an issue ticket is already created => https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-12183